# Replace all place holder of all the files in a folder

Tags: bash, unix, sh

I need to write a bash script.
I have a folder name `abc` and the folder contains multiple (around 20) files. Now some of the files are named as `__servicename__List.java` Here `__servicename` is acting as a placeholder. I need to replace this placeholder with a string say `xyz`

Can someone please help?
Appreciate all your help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want 20 files with the same name?

Comment: not 20 files. few of them which has a placeholder with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

In bash I would do:

```
cd abc
for FileName in **/* ; do
    mv -- "$FileName" "${FileName/__servicename__/xyz}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I tried but somehow it didn't work. Did I miss something else?

Comment: Its says ```mv: cannot stat '**/*': No such file or directory```

Comment: Are you using bash, or sh ?
Also, are you in the right folder?
Try only `*` maybe.

Comment: I tires ```for FileName in * ; do
  mv -- "$FileName" "${FileName/_servicename_/$Service_Name}"
 done``` its still not working. Did I miss something?

Comment: I tried ```$Service_Name="xyz" for FileName in * ; do
  mv -- "$FileName" "${FileName/_servicename_/$Service_Name}"
 done``` its still not working. Did I miss something?

Comment: @SwetaSharma sorry for the late answer, but yes you missed somthing. In Bash, assignment to a variable is `var=content`, not `$var=content`.